# Instantiation oddity

Tags: c++

I have a problem whereby a vector of pointers does not seem to be behaving in the polymorphic way I expected it to. Stranger is the fact that it works on every other object it points to.

`shotgunNodes` and `rifleNodes` both contain two integers which represent the appropriate location in a level to place the pickups I'm generating.

`pickups` is a vector of kpointers (parent class) and `ShotgunPU` and `RiflePU` are derived classes. I'll post the headers and source below.

The strange problem is that if I break the code, one loop at a time, everything seems to be going fine. The first gun pointer is set to point at a rifle object. Fine. Then the next gun pointer is set to point at the next rifle object, at which point for some bizarre reason the previous pointer in the vector, that should point to the first rifle is cut down and now only points to the gun part of the rifle object, so I lose all of the derived functionality on it.

By the end of the loops, I have a vector of guns pointing to Gun Rifle Gun Shotgun where it should be Rifle Rifle Shotgun Shotgun.

```
int j = 0;

for (vec_i_sz i = 0; i < rifleNodes.size(); i++, j++)
{
    riflePickups.push_back(RiflePU(agents, mesh));
    riflePickups[i].Position(nodes[rifleNodes[i]].Position());

    pickups.push_back(&riflePickups[i]);//point the pickup pointer to the rifle pickup
    pickups[j]->Index(j);
    pickups[j]->NodeIndex(rifleNodes[i]);
}

for (vec_i_sz i = 0; i < shotgunNodes.size(); i++, j++)
{
    shotgunPickups.push_back(ShotgunPU(agents, mesh));
    shotgunPickups[i].Position(nodes[shotgunNodes[i]].Position());

    pickups.push_back(&shotgunPickups[i]);
    pickups[j]->Index(j);
    pickups[j]->NodeIndex(shotgunNodes[i]);
}
```

It's probably also worth noting that this code (obviously the translated version, but in the same structure) works in the C# version of the program. So I doubt it's the structure of the code. Is there something I don't know about the way pointers work?

This is how the vectors are declared in the header where they are used:

```
std::vector<Pickup*> pickups;
std::vector<RiflePU> riflePickups;
std::vector<ShotgunPU> shotgunPickups;
```

I just noticed by writing this that they are not actually initialized in the initializer list before the loops run (in the constructor's body), but shouldn't this be OK because they are class types?

If they are being initialised in the list, it's still happening.

```
pickups(std::vector<Pickup*>()),
riflePickups(std::vector<RiflePU>()),
shotgunPickups(std::vector<ShotgunPU>())
```

Comment: Post **minimal** code that exibits the problem. If you can't bother narrowing it down, why would anyone bother reading that whole thing?

Comment: the long code-posting aside: what exactly is the problem? please describe the problem so that anyone understands it _BEFORE_ reading kilobytes of text.

Comment: furthermore: you provide all the code for guns and bullets etc (which is secondary), but you left out the declaration for 'pickups' and 'riflePickups' and 'shotgunPickups' ... which might be much more interesting since you access / modify these containers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore can't be bothered? It took more effort to post the code than not. I thought it was relevant but it's gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add items to a vector, `push_back` can invalidate all pointers into the container when it needs to resize its underlying buffer. Each time this happens, the pointers that you have already stored in `pick_ups` become garbage.

1) You can `reserve` memory for all items in `riflePickups` and `shotgunPickups` upfront. This will ensure that those vectors won't be resized while that many items are added, and addresses of items will remain the same.

2) You can store the pointers in `pick_ups` **after** you have created all the items in both vectors, not while those vectors have not yet reached their final size.

3) You can use `std::list` over vector for `riflePickups` and `shotgunPickups`. In a list, pointers to items are only invalidated if said item is erased.

---

Eventually, do you really need any of this? Perhaps you could just store (preferably smart) pointers to dynamically allocated objects in just one vector.

Comment: This is fantastic, I didn't know any of this. just one thing, could you link me to some info about smart pointers? I can't find any good resources on them.

Answer (score 0):

"visitor" has explained what happens, and as he hints, I think your fundamental problem is that you use objects when you should be using pointers to objects. Remember that C# (and Java) really uses pointers to all objects, even if it's not evident from the syntax. So while this C# code:

```
Person daisy = new Person();
daisy.salary = 39000;
dosomethingwith(daisy);
```

would compile as C++ too, if you just remove the keword **new**, what happens when it is executed is closer to this C++ code:

```
Person* daisy = new Person();
daisy->salary = 39000;
dosomethingwith(daisy);
```

It is a common mistake by Java and C# programmers that transfer to C++ that they create all objects with **new**, but perhaps the opposite is true too.